# Implement string contains function in Python with lambda expression

Tags: python

```
>>> a='test1'
>>> check_for_test1=lambda x:a in x
>>> check_for_test1('test1')
True
>>> a='test2'
>>> check_for_test2=lambda x:a in x
>>> check_for_test2('test1')
False
>>> check_for_test2('test2')
True
>>> check_for_test1('test1')
False
```

Is there any way I can keep check_for_test1 to be on the "original" test variable , i.e. test1?

Comment: This is a mess. You have named lambdas, which should be avoided according to PEP8 and you're changing globals. Whatever route this is going down.... I have a bad feeling about it

Comment: Thanks for your input sir. I have tried to recreate a concise example in order to better understand my problem. And I share your view of assigning names lambdas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use a closure:

```
>>> a='test1'
>>> check_for_test1 = (lambda needle: lambda x: needle in x)(a)
>>> check_for_test1('test1')
True
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> check_for_test1('test1')
True
```

Note, **you should avoid assigning the result of a lambda expression to a name**. The **only purpose** of `lambda` is so a function is *anonymous*. This is actually explicitly against PEP8 style guidelines.

This is generally called a factory function.

I would say, a more pythonic way would be:

```
def make_checker(needle):
    def checker(x):
        return needle in x
    return checker
```

Which is much clearer to me.

Comment: @ggorlen sure, although, the principle applies to anything.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I really like the second option while the first option shed light on my understanding of scopes and closures.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the original value in the keyword argument with default value:

```
a='test1'
check_for_test1=lambda x, a=a:a in x
print( check_for_test1('test1') )
a='test2'
check_for_test2=lambda x, a=a:a in x
print( check_for_test2('test1') )
print( check_for_test2('test2') )
print( check_for_test1('test1') )
```

Prints:

```
True
False
True
True
```

**Note:** everything **bad** about named lambdas in the comments apply. Don't use them it you don't have to.

Comment: Yes, works as advertised. And thanks, I will stay away from named lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the functions to change when you update the value of `a` then use the string itself rather than a variable.

```
check_for_test1=lambda x: 'test1' in x
check_for_test2=lambda x: 'test2' in x
```

Comment: Your example would work for constant strings but the value of a is changed during the runtime and I need the function created to keep the original value. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

you can use functions with constants, cleaner code:

```
TEST1 = 'test1'
TEST2 = 'test2'

def check_for_test1(my_str):
    return TEST1 in my_str

def check_for_test2(my_str):
    return TEST2 in my_str
```

if you want to create dynamically  the check methods:

```
def check_method_creator(my_str):
    def check_method(other_str):
        return my_str in other_str
    return check_method

check_for_test1 = check_method_creator('test1')
check_for_test2 = check_method_creator('test2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I specifically used/required variable a because the check function should be dynamically created during the runtime.

Comment: @CezarSuteu what about now?